# event.preventDefault(); not working in ajax post laravel Framework 5.8.17

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, preventdefault

Hello generally it works elsewhere but this specific AJAX Post preventDefault() not working for me.

I am getting some value dynamically, I am setting that value to form's hidden fields and then triggering ajax Post to another ROUTE.

Following is code part for which i need any help or assistance.

```
<!--Init_Form_ST-->
<div style="display:none;">
  <form id="frm_init" name="frm_init" action="{{ route('init_message') }}" method="POST"   >
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('POST') }}
    <input type="hidden" name="init_messageType" id="init_messageType" value="chatMessage" >
    <input type="hidden" name="init_idempotencyid" id="init_idempotencyid" value="" >
    <input type="hidden" name="init_receveruserid" id="init_receveruserid" value="" >
    <input type="hidden" name="init_lang" id="init_lang" value="" >    
    <?php /*?><input type="submit" name="init_submit" id="init_submit" value="init_sub" ><?php */?>
    <button type="submit" name="init_submit" id="init_submit" ></button>
  </form>        
</div>
<!--Init_Form_EN-->
```

I tried different methods to prevent form from getting submitted and navigate to another page.

```js
alert("1st Alert - Before Click Trigger");
$("#init_submit").trigger('click');
alert("2nd Alert - After Click Trigger");

$("#frm_init").on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  alert("3rd Alert - Into submit"); // <== It never comes here

  var init_formdata = new FormData(this);
  var init_msg_route = "{{ route('init_message') }}";

  $.ajax({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    url: init_msg_route,
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: init_formdata,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(result) {
      alert("Success");
    },
    error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
      alert('Exception:', exception);
    }
  });
});
```

pointer Goes to **1st Alert** and waits for button click. After that pointer shows **2nd Alert** but without waiting page navigates to route path.

I even tested by removing all Ajax code. But **3rd Alert** never triggers

I have already tested with following options

```
// $("#frm_init").submit(function(event){
// $(document).on("submit","frm_init", function(event) {                                                                
// $(document).on("click","#init_submit", function(event) { 
// $("#init_submit").click(function(event){
```

Comment: tried adding breakpoints ?  any errors in your console ?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Also, are you absolutely certain that `id` selector is correct? Is there multiple forms with the same `id` in the DOM? Also, remove `async: false`. It's terrible practice, and you don't need it

Comment: @Viral try `alert("3rd Alert - Into submit");  return false;` and remove event.preventDefault() , see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for quick responses.  

At maximum I can see @ 1st Alert No console error 
-- On 2nd Alert it comes and then redirects to ROUTE path.

Comment: @Viral open your website in the web browser `ctrl + U` ( on windows ) now search how many id's are there with the name `#frm_init`

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions. I tested "return false;" that did not helped. And also verified that NO more than 1 ID is linked with "frm_init".

Comment: @Viral , a link maybe needed to look into this unless you can recreate this scenario using https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks everyone. Specially @AlexanderSolonik for your suggestion. I found one silly mistakes. I am triggering form submit Before and after that I am writing code On Form submit. "On form submit" should come before "Trigger form submit"

thanks all

Answer (score 2):

I found one silly mistakes. 
I am Triggering "Form Submit" before catching "On Form Submit"

This may help someone who might do silly mistakes like me. 
Thanks everyone for all your helps.

[image]